# Should you put USER data in tables within a single MySQL database, or have a separate database for USER data?

Tags: mysql

Is there an advantage to separating user data into a separate MySQL database from the main application database? The number of tables in a db can add up, and separating them by function seems a good way to reduce the clutter.

Comment: that is a very vague question and needs much more information what you think is user data and what you want to split up

Answer (score 0):

The way I was told to think about your database data is that if you are going to be referencing the data again it should be in a separate table, just like if you are likely to enter the same data more than once it should be in a separate table and then linked or joined.

Using a separate Database is a little excessive.

For example lets say you have a user, who has an email address and a postal address.
There is a chance that the postal address could be used by more than one user (family members for example) so I would then put the User, eMail address and Postal Address into different tables each using the User row id as a join between each table.